# WORD VSTO - seleccionar una pagina en especifico y cambiar margenes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

estoy tratando de aplicar margenes diferentes a paginas distintas segun si la pagina es par o impar

```
public void macro(Document doc)
    {
        object Miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic PagesCountStat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages;
        int PagesCount = doc.ComputeStatistics(PagesCountStat, ref Miss);
        MessageBox.Show("Paginas totales: " + PagesCount);
        float imparIzq = 0;
        float imparDer = 0;
        float parIzq = 2;
        float parDer = 2;

        object What = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
        object Which = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute;
        object CurrentPageNumber;
        object NextPageNumber;

        var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        for (int x = 0; x <= PagesCount; x++)
        {
            CurrentPageNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()));
            NextPageNumber = (Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString() + 1));


            doc.Application.Selection.GoTo(ref What, ref Which, ref CurrentPageNumber, ref Miss);
            Range rge = doc.Application.Selection.Range;
            doc.Application.Selection.GoTo(ref What, ref Which, ref CurrentPageNumber, ref Miss);
            rge.End = doc.Application.Selection.Range.End;
            doc.Application.Selection.Select();

            if (x % 2 == 0)//paginas pares
            {
                doc.Application.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin = parIzq;
                doc.Application.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin = parDer;
            }
            else //paginas impares
            {
                doc.Application.Selection.PageSetup.LeftMargin = imparIzq;
                doc.Application.Selection.PageSetup.RightMargin = imparDer;
            }
        }

    }
```

Por más que lo intente no se cambian los margenes de la pagina, no hace nada o solo se cambiar a nivel global el ultimo margen. Agradezco de antemano si alguien puede ayudarme.